# preference :override class Pdfcreditmemos and class PrintAction not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php, magento2.4

I override the classes 'Pdfcreditmemos.php' and 'PrintAction.php' to change the name of pdf Credit memos , but this is not working, it still works with origin classes, thanks for you help.

```
Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\Pdfcreditmemos
Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\PrintAction
```

```
*************di.xml
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\Pdfcreditmemos" type="Lcdr\InvoicePdf\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\Pdfcreditmemos"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\PrintAction" type="Lcdr\InvoicePdf\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\PrintAction"/>
```

```
    Pdfcreditmemos.php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Lcdr\InvoicePdf\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

/**
 * Class Pdfcreditmemos
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Pdfcreditmemos extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\Pdfcreditmemos
{
    
    public function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $pdf = $this->pdfCreditmemo->getPdf($collection);
        $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

        return $this->fileFactory->create(
            sprintf('creditmemoaaaaaaaa%s.pdf', $this->dateTime->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s')),
            $fileContent,
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/pdf'
        );
    }
}
```

```
    PrintAction.php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Lcdr\InvoicePdf\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class PrintAction extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Creditmemo\AbstractCreditmemo\PrintAction
{
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @see \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice */
        $creditmemoId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('creditmemo_id');
        if ($creditmemoId) {
            $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoRepository->get($creditmemoId);
            if ($creditmemo) {
                $pdf = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Creditmemo::class
                )->getPdf(
                    [$creditmemo]
                );
                $date = $this->_objectManager->get(
                    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::class
                )->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
                $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

                return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                    'creditmemokkkkkkkkk' . $date . '.pdf',
                    $fileContent,
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/pdf'
                );
            }
        } else {
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to magento standard, An `abstract class` cannot be overridden.

As per your post, you want to do some customization on `public function massAction` and `public function execute()` method.

Those both are public function then you can use `plugin` for customization.